# Can redis hold more than what the RAM allows?

Tags: redis

Can redis hold more values than what the RAM allows, as in if the box's memory is 16 GBs can it hold 20 GB worth of (redis compressed that is) key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't. It only uses memory.

See the FAQ: http://redis.io/topics/faq